# ArcGIS Dissolve leaving feature snippets in dissolved polyons. Repair doesn't fix

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dissolve

I'm trying to dissolve some low-level polygons, but the result I'm getting has lots of little pieces of lines left floating around in the output polygons. I've tried doing "repair geometry" on both the input featureclass (before dissolving) and on the output featureclass (after dissolve) and neither fixes the problem.

Any thoughts?

[Edit: Also: dissolve running without errors, oddly.]

[image: Dissolve issue image]

Comment: have you tried running dissolve on your dissolved layer?

Comment: The problem is most likely unclean topology in the original data, as Branco mentions. There are two main approaches to fixing - clean up the topology in the original data (Integrate comes to mind), or eliminate the slivers created in the resulting data. Some solutions (available at other questions here on GIS.SE) can work on either end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be possible that the topology is off a bit and there are tiny little gaps in between your polygons.

If that is the case, a discussion entitled **[Polygon - Dissolve; leaves "cracks" in the polygon feature](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/29323-Polygon-Dissolve-leaves-quot-cracks-quot-in-the-polygon-feature)** may be pretty helpful.

Try zooming in very, very close to see if you see anything.  Add a fill color to the polygons to help make gaps easier to see.

Comment: There are! You're the (wo?)man -- thank you so much for this.